# react-virtualized table row width will not change on resizing window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

When i resize window,  header resizes too but rows keep same width unless i scroll. Is there a way to resize rows immediatelly after window changes size ?

```
    <AutoSizer>
        {({ height, width }) => (
     <Table2
     height={height}
     width={width}
     headerHeight={80}
     rowHeight={100}
     rowCount={list.length}
     rowStyle={{ borderRadius: 20, backgroundColor: "#555", borderBottomStyle: "solid"}}
     headerStyle={{backgroundColor: "grey", border: "solid", borderColor: "grey", borderRadius: 10}}
     rowGetter={({index}) => list[index]}>
    {(() => {const vysledok = tableHeaderConfig.map((tableHeaderConfig, columnIndex) => {
      return <Column  width={(() => columnIndex < 5 ? 300 : 1000)()} 
                    style={{
                      whiteSpace:"normal", 
                      display: "flex", 
                      justifyContent: "center", 
                      border: "solid", 
                      borderColor: "transparent", 
                      color: "white", 
                      textShadow: "2px 2px 8px black"}} 
                    headerRenderer={() => sortHeader(tableHeaderConfig)}  
                    cellRenderer={({rowData, rowIndex})=>
                        getObjectTable(rowData, rowIndex, {name:tableHeaderConfig["name"], sortType:tableHeaderConfig["sortType"]})}/>                  
    }); return vysledok})()}
   </Table2>
    )}
    </AutoSizer>
```